# Using function to talk to USB device

Tags: visual-c++, driver, header-files

I want to use MPUSBWrite and MPUSBRead to talk to my LAC USB device. The functions are declared in a header file. The following is a snippet code:

mpusbapi.h snippet code

```
DWORD (*MPUSBRead)(HANDLE handle,           // Input
            PVOID pData,                // Output
            DWORD dwLen,                // Input
            PDWORD pLength,             // Output
            DWORD dwMilliseconds);      // Input

DWORD (*MPUSBWrite)(HANDLE handle,          // Input
             PVOID pData,               // Input
             DWORD dwLen,               // Input
             PDWORD pLength,            // Output
             DWORD dwMilliseconds);     // Input
```

You can assume that in my test.cpp, I have linked the .dll and opened connection to the device correctly (which I have).

Now I want to use MPUSBWrite() and MPUSBRead(). The data formatting for the device is found on page 6 of [LAC Advanced Config](http://www.firgelli.com/Uploads/LAC_Advanced_Configuration.pdf). Please advise on how to send and receive data from the device! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to mikrocontroller.net/attachment/9321/MPUSBAPI.txt and it describes the variables.